# Big file overwriten with a 0B file

Tags: linux, ubuntu, filesystems

I just opend for write (by mistake) a big file with data (about 200 MB). Now I have this file and it has 0B. I want to know If I can find raw data on disk for recovery... ?

Comment: If this is important to you and the file is on the same partition as `/tmp`, `/home`, `/run`, or `/var`, you should shut the system down until you find a way to recover the data.

Comment: Maybe, but it is difficult. First, as goldilocks says, immediately stop writing anything to that filesystem. What do you know about the file? Is it a known file type (e.g. video, sound)? What filesystem type was it on?

Comment: Add to your question which filesystem you're using. Whatever recovery options there might be, they are more or less filesystem dependent and thus a working answer most likely is not coming unless we know what you're using.

Comment: We're kinda flying blind here: Do you have an SSD or HDD? How much space is free on your HDD/SSD? Which version of Linux are you using? Which filesystem?  WHat's the model of the drive?  Do you have another drive you can use to clone the existing drive to? http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/the-best-ways-to-recover-data-on-linux/ and http://www.linux.org/threads/undelete-files-on-linux-systems.4316/ provide some ideas to you.